# Views Slideshow with numbered navigation disappears

Tags: 6, javascript, views, nodes

So a little background on my current setup. The views slideshow having issues is on the homepage:
http://pacificwhale.org

I am running Drupal 6, and using Views slideshow 2.4 with nodequeue to feed 6 nodes that are of the photo content type. The slideshow that I am working closely with sits on the homepage of my website. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. When it stops working, the numbered navigation disappears from the page, and in the source code, I'm noticing that the jQuery.extend function call in the html page header is missing this code:

> "viewsSlideshowSingleFrame": {
>   "#views_slideshow_singleframe_main_nodequeue_1-block": { "num_divs":
>   6, "id_prefix": "#views_slideshow_singleframe_main_", "div_prefix":
>   "#views_slideshow_singleframe_div_", "vss_id": "nodequeue_1-block",
>   "timeout": 5000, "sort": 1, "effect": "fade", "speed": 700,
>   "start_paused": 0, "delay": 0, "fixed_height": 1, "random": 0,
>   "pause": 2, "pause_on_click": 0, "pause_when_hidden": 0,
>   "pause_when_hidden_type": "full", "amount_allowed_visible": "",
>   "remember_slide": 0, "remember_slide_days": 1, "controls": 0,
>   "items_per_slide": 1, "pager": 2, "pager_type": "Numbered",
>   "pager_hover": 1, "pager_click_to_page": 0, "image_count": 0,
>   "nowrap": 0, "sync": 1, "advanced": "", "ie": { "cleartype": "true",
>   "cleartypenobg": "false" } } } });

To view the html for the slideshow you can do a view source from our homepage.

To make the numbered navigation work, I must from the admin area of drupal6 perform a "flush all caches" from a page *other than* the homepage. After doing this, if I navigate to the homepage while logged into the admin area, the slideshow will not work, and there will be no numbered navigation. However, if I log out of the admin area and then navigate to the homepage and view the slideshow, I notice that the numbers are working and the slideshow automatically rotates through my images.

An interesting oddity, is that if I am logged into the admin area and I perform a "flush all caches" from the homepage, then the slideshow will display navigation and work inside the admin area, but if I log out of the admin area, it will not display the numbered menu, and for me or any other viewer of the website the slideshow is broken with no navigation, and the jQuery.extend function is missing the viewsSlideshowSingleFrame variable settings.

Another interesting oddity is that the slideshow navigation once fixed by flush all caches, later on it will revert back to not working, and I must go through the steps again to get it to work, and I'm in a hopeless cycle to get it to work again.

I've attached a screen capture of my views setting for nodequeue_1. You'll notice that I've turned off caching for this view/nodequeue, so I don't understand why flushing all caches makes a difference in fixing the slideshow navigation.

[image: my nodequeue settings]

Answer (score 1):

Hi I don't normally post replies but I had a similar issue to you where my Carousel module with slide show stopped working in December 2013

Only when logged in as admin would I see the correct view

I was sure this has stopped about the time i updated some modules

After a bit of trial an error I noticed that the upgrade from 1.3 on 1.4 on Responsive Menus Module caused the issue

By using a 1.3 module the problem went away

Check which version you are using under 'Modules' and 'USER INTERFACE' section of administrator menu